Preamble a mess
I've been creating a document in overleaf and gradually adding to the preamble over time.
I am now receiving error messages saying "Too many symbol fonts defined" and "Symbol font `numbers' not defined". I predict that this is caused by conflicting packages though not entirely sure.
I've included my preamble within a sample file that generates the error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.
\documentclass{beamer}
  %%%%% Packages %%%%%
    \usepackage{pgfpages}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amsmath,scalerel} 
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{listofitems}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{fontawesome5} 
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{bbox,shapes.geometric,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,
    calc,petri,arrows,decorations.markings,shapes,calligraphy,positioning,backgrounds,decorations.text, shapes.geometric,math}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \usepackage{MnSymbol}
    \usepackage{pgffor}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}


\end{document}


always start from an empty preamble and only add packages as needed. In this case you should remove all packages shown.

Unfortunately I've added them as I've needed them (based on the different things I've made within the file), I'm just a bit of a beginner so wasn't aware that they were interfering with each other until recently. If I start removing packages I'm not sure how it will effect my overall project. That said, if starting from scratch is my only option I guess that's what I'll need to do. Thanks for your suggestion.

no you can not need all these, do you really have junk text from lipsum in a real document? or junk text from blindtext? inputenc does nothing unless your latex is very old,  and xparse similarly does almost nothing in a current latex. the bm package will describe how to avoid this error with \newcommand\bmmax{3}\usepackage{bm} but honestly I would start by removing all these packages.

Thanks for these extra details. I will do as you suggest. Thanks David.

Success! I removed them all and then added them back slowly. These are the packages I'm not longer using. Thanks again.
% \usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}
% \usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{blindtext}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{xparse}

Along with following the suggestion by @DavidCarlisle, I suggest adding a few comments in the preamble to identify related groups of packages and what they're used for.  % Fonts would be one obvious group.  Such identification makes it much easier to avoid duplication, and add or remove packages as appropriate.

Thanks Barbara!

The MnSymbol is a problematic package, remove, as well as fontawesome and waysym .  If you need some of their symbols there are other ways to obtain them.
